# Is per-user API discovery necessary (Google Drive SDK)?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I have an app on Appengine which is based on the Python version of DrEdit from the Google Drive SDK samples.**

Although I haven't actually done any profiling yet, I have noticed that it seems to be building the Drive service and User Info service from scratch for every single request processed.  This seems very wasteful as it involves making an http request and then parsing the returned JSON in a relatively complex way.

I've checked the general example in the [python google client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started) to see if it's done more efficiently, but it looks the same...

```
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)
```

Is it done this way because API discovery is user-specific (I've not seen mention of this anywhere), or is it just a lazy way of getting the authorised http object into the service object?  I'm new to python and GAE, so I might have overlooked some sort of clever caching that is occurring, either of the http request or even the generated object, though I think both are unlikely.

**Questions:**
Am I correct in thinking this is wasteful?  If so, does anyone know roughly how many milliseconds it's likely to be wasting per-request on an F1-class GAE server? And does anyone know of a modified discovery.py module which allows for reuse of the service across users.

**I have made a reasonable number of changes to the sample, including switching to python 2.7 and using online OAuth2 with credentials only stored in memcache.

**Edit:**
I have just installed appstats (which wasn't as complicated as I'd feared!).  It seems that the http request in question takes about 60-75ms.  So if you want to do two - one for Drive and one for UserInfo (and they're synchronous) - you're wasting about 120-150ms per request.  An amount that seems worth saving.

And what about using the execute() command on the service [asynchronously](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests), that would allow requests to drive, userinfo, and memcache/datastore to be done simultaneously.  (Logically that is possible in my app at least).  Would this require (another) re-write of discovery.py or is there an easier way to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is wasteful. Try turning caching on which should reduce the network I/O significantly:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/performance#cache

my guess is that will knock the 60-75ms time down by a factor of 4 or 5.